# Estoy haciendo el clasico ejemplo de la calculadora, pero solo suma los numeros con decimales correctamente 1 vez

Tags: c#, visual-studio, double, parsear

como puse en el enunciado, estoy siguiendo un ejemplo para c# en el cual se hace una caculadora simple, hasta ahora la calculadora estaba funcionando perfectamente, sin embargo estoy teniendo bastantes problemas con los numeros decimales, al principio, el problema era que debido al programar en españa, la calculadora solo sumaba los numeros si usaba un "," en vez de un ".", sin embargo por algo que no entiendo el resultado me lo devolvia con "." ejemplo

1,1 + 1,1 = 2.2

Así que buscando encontre personas que tenian problemas con los decimales y usaban invariant culture, y así hice, ahora todas las conversiones de double.Tryparse() con invariantCulture y luego con new CurrentCulture (en-US), con esto consegui que

1.1 + 1.1 = 2.2

El problema es que cuando vuelvo a sumar el resultado previo.

2.2 + 1.1 = 23.1

y me esta volviendo loco perdido, por más que pruebo sigue haciendo lo mismo y no lo entiendo, copio y pego el código C#

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace calculadora
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        SelectedOperator selectedOperator;
        Double primerNumero;
        Double segundoNumero;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            acButton.Click += AcButton_Click;
            negativeButton.Click += NegativeButton_Click;
            percentegeButton.Click += PercentegeButton_Click;
        }

        private void PercentegeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (double.TryParse(resultLabel.Content.ToString(), out double auxiliar))
            {
                resultLabel.Content = auxiliar / 100;   
            }
        }

        private void NegativeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (double.TryParse(resultLabel.Content.ToString(),out double auxiliar))
            {
                resultLabel.Content = auxiliar * -1;
            }
        }

        private void AcButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            resultLabel.Content = "0";
        }


        private void OperationButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (double.TryParse(resultLabel.Content.ToString(), NumberStyles.Any, new CultureInfo("en-US"), out primerNumero))
            {
                resultLabel.Content = "0";
            }

            if (sender == asteriskButton)
                selectedOperator = SelectedOperator.Multiplication;

            if (sender == divisionButton)
                selectedOperator = SelectedOperator.Division;

            if (sender == plusButton)
                selectedOperator = SelectedOperator.Addition;

            if (sender == minusButton)
                selectedOperator = SelectedOperator.Sustraction;
        }

        private void NumberButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {        
            if (resultLabel.Content.ToString().Equals("0"))
            {
                resultLabel.Content = (sender as Button).Content.ToString(); 
            }
            else
            {
                resultLabel.Content = $"{resultLabel.Content}{(sender as Button).Content.ToString()}";
            }
        }

        public enum SelectedOperator{
            Addition,
            Sustraction,
            Multiplication,
            Division
        }

        private void equalButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (double.TryParse(resultLabel.Content.ToString(), NumberStyles.Any, new CultureInfo("en-US"), out segundoNumero))
            {
                switch (selectedOperator)
                {
                    case SelectedOperator.Addition:
                        resultLabel.Content = suma(primerNumero,segundoNumero);
                        break;
                    case SelectedOperator.Division:
                        resultLabel.Content = primerNumero / segundoNumero;
                        break;
                    case SelectedOperator.Multiplication:
                        resultLabel.Content = primerNumero * segundoNumero;
                        break;
                    case SelectedOperator.Sustraction:
                        resultLabel.Content = primerNumero - segundoNumero;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        private void dotButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!resultLabel.Content.ToString().Contains("."))
            {
                resultLabel.Content = $"{resultLabel.Content}.";
            }
        }

        private double suma(double n1, double n2)
        {
            return (n1 + n2);
        }
    }
}
```

El Xaml del código es el siguiente

```
    <Window x:Class="calculadora.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:calculadora"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="525" Width="350">
    <Grid Margin="10">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label x:Name="resultLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
               VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
               FontSize="60" 
               Content="0" 
               Grid.ColumnSpan="4"/>
        <Button x:Name="acButton" Content="AC" 
                Margin="5" 
                Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Button x:Name="negativeButton" Content="+/-" 
                Margin="5" 
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Button x:Name="percentegeButton" Content="%" 
                Margin="5" 
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="2"/>
        <Button x:Name="divisionButton" Content="/" 
                Margin="5" 
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="3"
                Click="OperationButton_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="sevenButton" Content="7" 
                Margin="5" 
                Grid.Row="2"
                Click="NumberButton_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="eightButton" Content="8" 
                Margin="5" 
                Grid.Row="2"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Click="NumberButton_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="nineButton" Content="9" 
                Margin="5" 
                Grid.Row="2"
                Grid.Column="2"
                Click="NumberButton_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="asteriskButton" Content="*" 
                Margin="5" 
                Grid.Row="2"
                Grid.Column="3"
                Click="OperationButton_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="fourButton" Content="4" 
                Margin="5" 
                Grid.Row="3"
                Click="NumberButton_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="fiveButton" Content="5" 
                Margin="5" 
                Grid.Row="3"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Click="NumberButton_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="sixButton" Content="6" 
                Margin="5" 
                Grid.Row="3"
                Grid.Column="2"
                Click="NumberButton_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="minusButton" Content="-" 
                Margin="5" 
                Grid.Row="3"
                Grid.Column="3"
                Click="OperationButton_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="oneButton" Content="1" 
                Margin="5" 
                Grid.Row="4"
                Click="NumberButton_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="twoButton" Content="2" 
                Margin="5" 
                Grid.Row="4"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Click="NumberButton_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="thirdButton" Content="3" 
                Margin="5" 
                Grid.Row="4"
                Grid.Column="2"
                Click="NumberButton_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="plusButton" Content="+" 
                Margin="5" 
                Grid.Row="4"
                Grid.Column="3"
                Click="OperationButton_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="zeroButton" Content="0" 
                Margin="5" 
                Grid.Row="5"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                Click="NumberButton_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="dotButton" Content="." 
                Margin="5" 
                Grid.Row="5"
                Grid.Column="2"
                Click="dotButton_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="equalButton" Content="=" 
                Margin="5" 
                Grid.Row="5"
                Grid.Column="3"
                Click="equalButton_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Los títulos dan la idea general que serán descritos en el cuerpo del mensaje, úsalos bien, por favor :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error se encuentra al momento de asignar el resultado de la operación en el label resultLabel, debido a que no está aplicando el mismo formato utilizado cuando realiza los double.TryParse en los métodos equalButton_Click y OperationButton_Click.
Para no tener en muchas partes del código la parte de new CultureInfo("en-US") sería bueno dejarlo como una variable global.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    SelectedOperator selectedOperator;
    Double primerNumero;
    Double segundoNumero;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        acButton.Click += AcButton_Click;
        negativeButton.Click += NegativeButton_Click;
        percentegeButton.Click += PercentegeButton_Click;
    }

    private void PercentegeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (double.TryParse(resultLabel.Content.ToString(), out double auxiliar))
        {
            resultLabel.Content = auxiliar / 100;
        }
    }

    private void NegativeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (double.TryParse(resultLabel.Content.ToString(), out double auxiliar))
        {
            resultLabel.Content = auxiliar * -1;
        }
    }

    private void AcButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        resultLabel.Content = "0";
    }


    private void OperationButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (double.TryParse(resultLabel.Content.ToString(), NumberStyles.Any, cultureInfo, out primerNumero))
        {
            resultLabel.Content = "0";
        }

        if (sender == asteriskButton)
            selectedOperator = SelectedOperator.Multiplication;

        if (sender == divisionButton)
            selectedOperator = SelectedOperator.Division;

        if (sender == plusButton)
            selectedOperator = SelectedOperator.Addition;

        if (sender == minusButton)
            selectedOperator = SelectedOperator.Sustraction;
    }

    private void NumberButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (resultLabel.Content.ToString().Equals("0"))
        {
            resultLabel.Content = (sender as Button).Content.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            resultLabel.Content = $"{resultLabel.Content}{(sender as Button).Content.ToString()}";
        }
    }

    public enum SelectedOperator
    {
        Addition,
        Sustraction,
        Multiplication,
        Division
    }

    private void equalButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (double.TryParse(resultLabel.Content.ToString(), NumberStyles.Any, cultureInfo, out segundoNumero))
        {
            switch (selectedOperator)
            {
                case SelectedOperator.Addition:
                    resultLabel.Content = suma(primerNumero, segundoNumero).ToString(cultureInfo);
                    break;
                case SelectedOperator.Division:
                    resultLabel.Content = (primerNumero / segundoNumero).ToString(cultureInfo);
                    break;
                case SelectedOperator.Multiplication:
                    resultLabel.Content = (primerNumero * segundoNumero).ToString(cultureInfo);
                    break;
                case SelectedOperator.Sustraction:
                    resultLabel.Content = (primerNumero - segundoNumero).ToString(cultureInfo);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void dotButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!resultLabel.Content.ToString().Contains("."))
        {
            resultLabel.Content = $"{resultLabel.Content}.";
        }
    }

    private double suma(double n1, double n2)
    {
        return (n1 + n2);
    }
}
```

Se podría forzar la utilización del IFormatProvider desde el constructor MainWindow() y se eliminaría la mayor parte de conversiones.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    SelectedOperator selectedOperator;
    Double primerNumero;
    Double segundoNumero;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        acButton.Click += AcButton_Click;
        negativeButton.Click += NegativeButton_Click;
        percentegeButton.Click += PercentegeButton_Click;

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    }

    private void PercentegeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (double.TryParse(resultLabel.Content.ToString(), out double auxiliar))
        {
            resultLabel.Content = auxiliar / 100;
        }
    }

    private void NegativeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (double.TryParse(resultLabel.Content.ToString(), out double auxiliar))
        {
            resultLabel.Content = auxiliar * -1;
        }
    }

    private void AcButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        resultLabel.Content = "0";
    }


    private void OperationButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        primerNumero = Convert.ToDouble(resultLabel.Content);
        resultLabel.Content = "0";

        if (sender == asteriskButton)
            selectedOperator = SelectedOperator.Multiplication;

        if (sender == divisionButton)
            selectedOperator = SelectedOperator.Division;

        if (sender == plusButton)
            selectedOperator = SelectedOperator.Addition;

        if (sender == minusButton)
            selectedOperator = SelectedOperator.Sustraction;
    }

    private void NumberButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (resultLabel.Content.ToString().Equals("0"))
        {
            resultLabel.Content = (sender as Button).Content.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            resultLabel.Content = $"{resultLabel.Content}{(sender as Button).Content.ToString()}";
        }
    }

    public enum SelectedOperator
    {
        Addition,
        Sustraction,
        Multiplication,
        Division
    }

    private void equalButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        segundoNumero = Convert.ToDouble(resultLabel.Content);

        switch (selectedOperator)
        {
            case SelectedOperator.Addition:
                resultLabel.Content = (primerNumero + segundoNumero).ToString();
                break;
            case SelectedOperator.Division:
                resultLabel.Content = (primerNumero / segundoNumero).ToString();
                break;
            case SelectedOperator.Multiplication:
                resultLabel.Content = (primerNumero * segundoNumero).ToString();
                break;
            case SelectedOperator.Sustraction:
                resultLabel.Content = (primerNumero - segundoNumero).ToString();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void dotButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!resultLabel.Content.ToString().Contains("."))
        {
            resultLabel.Content = $"{resultLabel.Content}.";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No había pensado que hasta para asignar el resultado a una etiqueta habría que indicarle el cultureinfo, ¿hay alguna otra biblioteca para sumas de C# o externa que se ocupe de las sumas sin armar tanto lio? porque ahora mismo soy casi un novato total de C# pero es un lenguaje que me esta gustando y en un futuro me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de evitarse tanto caos de indicarle una y otra vez el cultureInfo en cada operación y asignación.